# Tkinter SimpleDialog Timeout

Tags: python, tkinter, timeout, simpledialog

I have a program that requires input to a module while it is running, so I am implementing a simple Dialog box to get input from the user to use in my Tkinter program. But I also need it to timeout when running the module as a console program, to pass over it or timeout after so many seconds when the user is not interacting with it. And not to have it just sit there and wait forever until the user interacts with it. How do I terminate the window after a timeout? Here is what I have now ...

```py
def loginTimeout(timeout=300):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    start_time = time.time()
    input1 = simpledialog.askinteger('Sample','Enter a Number')
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            chr = msvcrt.getche()
            if ord(chr) == 13: # enter_key
                break
            elif ord(chr) >= 32: #space_char
                input1 += chr
        if len(input1) == 0 and (time.time() - start_time) > timeout:
            break

    print('')  # needed to move to next line
    if len(input1) > 0:
        return input1
    else:
        return input1
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. what do you need help with? Also, why are you using msvcrt instead of tkinter's built-in event mechanism?

Comment: I am not sure, I was using the code I had from `input` timeout I used in the past, and thought it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what the question is, but you could use the tkinter `after()` method in a similar way to this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('100x100')

def get_entry() -> str:
    """Gets and returns the entry input, and closes the tkinter window."""
    entry = entry_var.get()
    root.destroy() # Edit: Changed from root.quit()
    return entry

# Your input box
entry_var = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_var).pack()

# A button, or could be an event binding that triggers get_entry()
tk.Button(root, text='Enter/Confirm', command=get_entry).pack()

# This would be the 'timeout'
root.after(5000, get_entry)

root.mainloop()
```

So, if the User enters something they can hit confirm or launch an event binded to the entry, or after the delay the program runs get_entry anyway. Maybe this will give you an idea, you can also check out the other widget methods:
https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

EDIT: I'm not sure how this is arranged in your program, but `root.mainloop()` blocks, so once it's running, code after it won't run until the mainloop() exits. If you're function is part of a toplevel() window, you could use `wait_window()` to prevent the function from advancing until your timeout destroys the toplevel window or the function is called before by the User. The example, although probably not the best solution, would be:

```
def loginTimeout(timeout_ms: int=5000):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x50')

    # function to get input and change the function variable
    input_ = ''
    def get_input():
        nonlocal input_
        input_ = entry_var.get()
        root.destroy()

    # build the widgets
    entry_var = tk.StringVar()
    tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_var).pack(side='left')
    tk.Button(root, text='Confirm', command=get_input).pack(side='right')

    # timeout
    root.after(timeout_ms, get_input)

    # mainloop
    root.mainloop()

    # won't get here until root is destroyed
    return input_

print(loginTimeout())
```

Comment: It worked after I changed it from `root.quit()` to `root.destroy()` and realized that the delay was in milliseconds rather than seconds

Comment: Yeah, `root.quit()` exits the entire Tlc interpreter, but glad it helped

Comment: I have this inside a function, how would I send the entry outside of this function? To assign it to another variable.

Comment: I have this inside a function, and calling it in another function, How would I send `entry` outside of this function? To assign it to another variable assigning the variable to the `after()` statement doesn't work and returning the variable after the `after()` doesn't work. Lastly assigning it to a global variable in the function and having it return the variable doesn't work

Comment: Where are you starting the `mainloop()`? Your initial function starts a new interpreter, as mine does, but I see yours doesn't call the mainloop of it, whereas mine does. So, if this is part of a larger application, just use the same mainloop, make this function create a new `Toplevel()` window, and use `wait_window()`.

Comment: If all you want to do is close the window? then in your original code change `break` after the timeout condition to `root.destroy()` or `root.quit()` whichever is required.